# Twitter API access using R's http

Tags: r, twitter, httr

I am tearing my hair out over this issue! I am pretty confident I am using the correct bearer token (I have reset this to check), I also have paid API access for twitter. I also don't believe I am over any rate limits, I am just confused.

The code started to produce blank tables of data so I set up a little helper function that tells me which bits fail.

It's basically producing the below error

Hopefully, someone can help :)

```
Failed to fetch tweets for nespresso
Failed to fetch tweets for keurig
Failed to fetch tweets for tassimo
Failed to fetch tweets for sage
Failed to fetch tweets for breville
Failed to fetch tweets for sense
```

Here is the code~

```
# Load necessary libraries
library(httr)
library(tidyverse)

bearer_token <- Sys.getenv("TWITTER_BEARER_TOKEN")

# Twitter API v2 endpoint for searching tweets
endpoint_url <- "https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/search/recent"

# List of competitors
competitors <- c("nespresso", "keurig", "tassimo", "sage", "breville", "senseo")

# Initialize a list to hold data for all competitors
all_tweets <- list()

# Function to compile tweets data
compile_tweets_data <- function(content_list) {
    map_df(content_list$data, ~tibble(
        Text = .x$text,
        AuthorID = .x$author_id,
        Likes = .x$public_metrics$like_count,
        Retweets = .x$public_metrics$retweet_count,
        Replies = .x$public_metrics$reply_count,
        Username = content_list$includes$users[[which(sapply(content_list$includes$users, function(u) u$id == .x$author_id))]]$username,
        Verified = content_list$includes$users[[which(sapply(content_list$includes$users, function(u) u$id == .x$author_id))]]$verified
    ))
}

# Functions to process API responses
process_response <- function(response, competitor) {
    if (http_status(response)$category == "success") {
        process_success(response, competitor)
    } else {
        message("Failed to fetch tweets for ", competitor)
        all_tweets[[competitor]] <- tibble()
    }
}

process_success <- function(response, competitor) {
    content_list <- content(response, as = "parsed", type = "application/json")
    
    if (!is.null(content_list$data)) {
        tweets_data <- compile_tweets_data(content_list)
        all_tweets[[competitor]] <- tweets_data
    } else {
        all_tweets[[competitor]] <- tibble()
    }
}

for (competitor in competitors) {
    # Construct the query parameters with additional fields
    params <- list(
        'query' = paste(competitor, "lang:en"),
        'max_results' = '10',
        'tweet.fields' = 'text,author_id,public_metrics',
        'expansions' = 'author_id',
        'user.fields' = 'username,verified'
    )
    
    # Make the GET request to the Twitter API
    response <- GET(url = endpoint_url, add_headers(Authorization = paste("Bearer", bearer_token)), query = params)
    
    # Process the response
    process_response(response, competitor)
}

# Combine all tweets into a single tibble
all_tweets_combined <- bind_rows(all_tweets, .id = "Competitor")
```

Comment: is your `httr` package updated

Comment: Yes, just checked with install.packages()

Comment: You seem to be throwing the error in your `process_response` function. Try print out the value of `http_status(response)` to see exactly what response you are getting. Also print out the body contents to see if there is a more detailed error message there, like`print(content(response, as="text"))`

Comment: I get `Client error: (400) Bad Request` which seems to tell me nothing. lol

Comment: is the body of request correct. Sometimes, the way the body of the structure can give you error like this.

Comment: Another option is take the body of API request used in your code and try it in postman or other api testing tool. This would tell you whether its strictly from R side.

Comment: Yes, I was actually going to try postman. My first step, that I am trying now, is to do this without loops and functions on a single brand name.

I seem to be getting somewhere!

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure what the issue was but I have isolated small part of it and found a way that works ... for now ...

Comment: I have figured it out. I was trying to be helpful with the "http_status(response)$category == "success" but it's actually "Success" with a capital s.

Comment: "(400) Bad Request" is still considered a "Success"? That's odd. You may want to use `httr::stop_for_status()` rather than doing string matching on that to find errors, which itself does `httr::status_code(x) < 300` to check for errors